# Splitting a Rust string into a Vec of its substrings with contiguous identical characters

Tags: string, vector, text, rust, sequence

I have a `string` or a `&str` of ASCII characters and I want to separate it into a `Vec` of all substrings with contiguous identical characters (for example, `"aabbca"` would become `["aa","bb","c","a"]`).

I could build a function that iterates over the individual characters and gradually builds a Vec of strings, but I have the feeling that I'd be reinventing the wheel.
Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Here's my intuitive (and current) solution, implemented for `&str`:

```
fn split_cont_chars(source:&str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut answer: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

    let mut head_char = source.chars().next().unwrap();
    let mut counter: usize = 1;

    for c in source.chars().skip(1) {
        if c == head_char {
            counter += 1;
        }
        else {
            answer.push(head_char.to_string().repeat(counter));
            head_char = c;
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    answer.push(head_char.to_string().repeat(counter));

    answer
}
```

This works as intended, but it is much more verbose than the average rust code that tackles iterative problems like these.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error messages did you get when you tried that? Did you get incorrect behaviour? It's going to be very hard to provide debugging help without more detail

Comment: I haven't written it yet, I was asking for the most idiomatic way to do it because my way seems suboptimal

Comment: The reason your question is being downvoted is because it doesn't follow SO guidelines. A good SO question would have a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem and some details about the problem (maybe an error message, incorrect behaviour, etc). If you haven't written anything yet, try writing it first, then come back and edit the question if you run into a problem. SO is not meant for open-ended questions. I'd recommend the Rust subreddit or official forums for open-ended questions

Comment: If you have some code that works but just looks messy or it *feels* suboptimal, there's also codereview.stackexchange.com , which is better suited for those sorts of questions

Comment: I see. It was my understanding that asking about idiomatic ways to accomplish things was considered less open-ended than a general question. English is also not my first language, and the diligent moderation on this site gives me a lot of anxiety because I phrase things in ways that don't conform with the duplicate questions autodetector

Comment: This question, and self-answer, are being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416729).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a more functional translation of the original solutions, but there is a more idiomatic one:

```
struct LetterSequence {
    char_type: char,
    len: usize
}

impl LetterSequence {
    fn new(a:char, b:usize) -> Self {
        LetterSequence{char_type:a, len:b}
    }
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        self.char_type.to_string().repeat(self.len)
    }
}

fn split_char_struct(source:&str) -> Vec<LetterSequence> {
    let mut answer: Vec<LetterSequence> = Vec::new();

    let mut seq_count: usize = 1;
    let mut head_char: char = source.chars().next().unwrap();

    for c in source.chars().skip(1) {
        if c == head_char {
            seq_count += 1;
        }
        else {
            answer.push(LetterSequence::new(head_char, seq_count));
            head_char = c;
            seq_count = 1;
        }
    }
    answer.push(LetterSequence::new(head_char, seq_count));

answer}
```

With the help of the `LetterSequence` struct, we avoid having to maintain potentially as many mutable strings as the total length of the starting `&str`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `itertools::Iterator::group_by` over `s.chars()` (with the identity function), but it'll inherently be inefficient because when it comes time to collect the chars into a String, you'll have to allocate a String for each result. I think the only way to get slices into the original String is to do it manually find the slices yourself. (If `itertools` offered a `group_by_indices` function, then you could use it to construct the slices, but AFAIK it does not.)

```rust
fn char_runs(s: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut slices = Vec::new();
    let mut it = s.char_indices();
    let (mut slice_start, mut prev_char) = match it.next() {
        Some(pair) => pair,
        None => return slices,
    };

    for (i, c) in it {
        if c != prev_char {
            slices.push(&s[slice_start..i]);
            slice_start = i;
            prev_char = c;
        }
    }

    slices.push(&s[slice_start..]);

    slices
}

fn main() {
    let strings = ["", "a", "aa", "aab", "aabb", "aabbca", "aabb"];
    for s in strings {
        println!("{:?} => {:?}", s, char_runs(s));
    }

    // "" => []
    // "a" => ["a"]
    // "aa" => ["aa"]
    // "aab" => ["aa", "b"]
    // "aabb" => ["aa", "bb"]
    // "aabbca" => ["aa", "bb", "c", "a"]
    // "aabb" => ["aa", "", "bb"]
}
```

Comment: Note that like any simple algorithm that touches Unicode, this will fail on some inputs for things that people will definitely count as one "character", eg. `"aabb" → ["aa", "", "", "", "", "bb"]`.